# React native state.token is undefined

Tags: react-native, jwt

I have created a backend that generates a json web token that logs the user in.

[image]

But when I go to the next screen the token is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Setting it:

```
  fetch('https://www.koolbusiness.com/account/mob_login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          "email": this.state.email,
          "password": this.state.password,
      }),
  }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
          this.state.token = responseJson.token;
```

Trying to use it in the next screen, then it is undefined.

Login screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,Alert,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
  LayoutAnimation,
  UIManager,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';
//import { Font } from 'expo';
import { Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements'

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import SimpleIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const BG_IMAGE = require('../../../assets/images/bg_screen4.jpg');

// Enable LayoutAnimation on Android
UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental
  && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);

const TabSelector = ({ selected }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.selectorContainer}>
      <View style={selected && styles.selected}/>
    </View>
  );
};

TabSelector.propTypes = {
  selected: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
let self;
export default class LoginScreen2 extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      fontLoaded: false,
      selectedCategory: 0,
      isLoading: false,
      isEmailValid: true,
      isPasswordValid: true,
      isConfirmationValid: true,
    };

    this.selectCategory = this.selectCategory.bind(this);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);
      self = this;
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
   // await Font.loadAsync({
    //  'georgia': require('../../../assets/fonts/Georgia.ttf'),
     // 'regular': require('../../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
      //'light': require('../../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
    //});

    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }

  selectCategory(selectedCategory) {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    this.setState({
      selectedCategory,
      isLoading: false,
    });
  }

  validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    return re.test(email);
  }

  login() {
    const {
      email,
      password,
        token
    } = this.state;



      fetch('https://www.koolbusiness.com/account/mob_login', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              "email": this.state.email,
              "password": this.state.password,
          }),
      }).then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
              self.setState({token:responseJson.token});
            //  this.state.token = responseJson.token;
              this.props.state = this.state;

              Alert.alert(
                  'Welcome',
                  'You are now logged in',
                  [
                      {text: responseJson.token, onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
                      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
                      {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                  ],
                  { cancelable: false }
              );
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
          });


    //this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    // Simulate an API call
    //setTimeout(() => {
    //  LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    //  this.setState({
    //    isLoading: false,
    //    isEmailValid: this.validateEmail(email) || this.emailInput.shake(),
    //    isPasswordValid: password.length >= 8 || this.passwordInput.shake(),
    //  });
    //}, 1500);

  }

  signUp() {
    const {
      email,
      password,
      passwordConfirmation,
    } = this.state;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    // Simulate an API call
    setTimeout(() => {
      LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        isEmailValid: this.validateEmail(email) || this.emailInput.shake(),
        isPasswordValid: password.length >= 8 || this.passwordInput.shake(),
        isConfirmationValid: password == passwordConfirmation || this.confirmationInput.shake(),
      });
    }, 1500);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      selectedCategory,
      isLoading,
      isEmailValid,
      isPasswordValid,
      isConfirmationValid,
      email,
      password,
      passwordConfirmation,
    } = this.state;
    const isLoginPage = selectedCategory === 0;
    const isSignUpPage = selectedCategory === 1;
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <ImageBackground
                  source={BG_IMAGE}
                  style={styles.bgImage}
              >
                  {this.state.fontLoaded ?
                      <View>
                          <KeyboardAvoidingView contentContainerStyle={styles.loginContainer} behavior='position'>
                              <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Login</Text>
                                  </View>
                                  <View style={{marginTop: -10, marginLeft: 10}}>
                                      <Text style={styles.titleText}>or Sign Up</Text>
                                  </View>
                              </View>
                              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                  <Button
                                      disabled={isLoading}
                                      clear
                                      activeOpacity={0.7}
                                      onPress={() => this.selectCategory(0)}
                                      containerStyle={{flex: 1}}
                                      titleStyle={[styles.categoryText, isLoginPage && styles.selectedCategoryText]}
                                      title={'Login'}
                                  />
                                  <Button
                                      disabled={isLoading}
                                      clear
                                      activeOpacity={0.7}
                                      onPress={() => this.selectCategory(1)}
                                      containerStyle={{flex: 1}}
                                      titleStyle={[styles.categoryText, isSignUpPage && styles.selectedCategoryText]}
                                      title={'Sign up'}
                                  />
                              </View>
                              <View style={styles.rowSelector}>
                                  <TabSelector selected={isLoginPage}/>
                                  <TabSelector selected={isSignUpPage}/>
                              </View>
                              <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                                  <Input
                                      icon={
                                          <Icon
                                              name='envelope-o'
                                              color='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'
                                              size={25}
                                              style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                                          />
                                      }
                                      value={email}
                                      keyboardAppearance='light'
                                      autoFocus={false}
                                      autoCapitalize='none'
                                      autoCorrect={false}
                                      keyboardType='email-address'
                                      returnKeyType='next'
                                      inputStyle={{marginLeft: 10}}
                                      placeholder={'Email'}
                                      containerStyle={{borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'}}
                                      ref={input => this.emailInput = input}
                                      onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                                      onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                                      displayError={!isEmailValid}
                                      errorMessage='Please enter a valid email address'
                                  />
                                  <Input
                                      icon={
                                          <SimpleIcon
                                              name='lock'
                                              color='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'
                                              size={25}
                                              style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                                          />
                                      }
                                      value={password}
                                      keyboardAppearance='light'
                                      autoCapitalize='none'
                                      autoCorrect={false}
                                      secureTextEntry={true}
                                      returnKeyType={isSignUpPage ? 'next' : 'done'}
                                      blurOnSubmit={true}
                                      containerStyle={{marginTop: 16, borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'}}
                                      inputStyle={{marginLeft: 10}}
                                      placeholder={'Password'}
                                      ref={input => this.passwordInput = input}
                                      onSubmitEditing={() => isSignUpPage ? this.confirmationInput.focus() : this.login()}
                                      onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                                      displayError={!isPasswordValid}
                                      errorMessage='Please enter at least 8 characters'
                                  />
                                  {isSignUpPage &&
                                  <Input
                                      icon={
                                          <SimpleIcon
                                              name='lock'
                                              color='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'
                                              size={25}
                                              style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                                          />
                                      }
                                      value={passwordConfirmation}
                                      secureTextEntry={true}
                                      keyboardAppearance='light'
                                      autoCapitalize='none'
                                      autoCorrect={false}
                                      keyboardType='default'
                                      returnKeyType={'done'}
                                      blurOnSubmit={true}
                                      containerStyle={{marginTop: 16, borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)'}}
                                      inputStyle={{marginLeft: 10}}
                                      placeholder={'Confirm password'}
                                      ref={input => this.confirmationInput = input}
                                      onSubmitEditing={this.signUp}
                                      onChangeText={passwordConfirmation => this.setState({ passwordConfirmation })}
                                      displayError={!isConfirmationValid}
                                      errorMessage='Please enter the same password'
                                  />}
                                  <Button
                                      buttonStyle={styles.loginButton}
                                      containerStyle={{marginTop: 32, flex: 0}}
                                      activeOpacity={0.8}
                                      title={isLoginPage ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP'}
                                      onPress={isLoginPage ? this.login : this.signUp}
                                      titleStyle={styles.loginTextButton}
                                      loading={isLoading}
                                      disabled={isLoading}
                                  />
                              </View>
                          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                          <View style={styles.helpContainer}>
                              <Button
                                  title={'Need help ?'}
                                  titleStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                                  buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                                  underlayColor='transparent'
                                  onPress={() => console.log('Account created')}
                              />
                          </View>
                      </View>
                      :
                      <Text>Loading...</Text>
                  }
              </ImageBackground>
          </View>
      );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  rowSelector: {
    height: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  selectorContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  selected: {
    position: 'absolute',
    borderRadius: 50,
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    top: -5,
    borderRightWidth: 70,
    borderBottomWidth: 70,
    borderColor: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  loginContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  loginTextButton: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(232, 147, 142, 1)',
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: 50,
    width: 200,
  },
  titleContainer: {
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  formContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 30,
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingTop: 32,
    paddingBottom: 32,
    alignItems:'center',
  },
  loginText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
  bgImage: {
    flex: 1,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
    height: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  categoryText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 24,

    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    opacity: 0.54,
  },
  selectedCategoryText: {
    opacity: 1,
  },
  titleText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,

  },
  helpContainer: {
    height: 64,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Next screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'


const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const IMAGE_SIZE = SCREEN_WIDTH - 80;

class CustomButton extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            selected: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { selected } = this.props;

        this.setState({
            selected
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { title } = this.props;
        const { selected } = this.state;

        return (
            <Button
                title={title}
                titleStyle={{ fontSize: 15, color: 'white' }}
                buttonStyle={selected ? { backgroundColor: 'rgba(213, 100, 140, 1)', borderRadius: 100, width: 127 } : { borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', borderRadius: 30, width: 127, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
                containerStyle={{ marginRight: 10 }}
                onPress={() => this.setState({ selected: !selected })}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default class LoginScreen1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

            fontLoaded: false,
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {


       this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
    }

    render() {


        Alert.alert(
            'Token '+this.state.token,
            'You are now logged in',
            [
                {text: this.state.token, onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
                {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
                {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
        );


        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <StatusBar
                    barStyle="light-content"
                />
                { this.state.fontLoaded ?
                    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgba(47,44,60,1)'}}>
                        <View style={styles.statusBar} />
                        <View style={styles.navBar}>
                            <Text style={styles.nameHeader}>
                                Johanna Bloggs, 26
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
                            <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                <Image
                                    source={{ uri: 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/428336/pexels-photo-428336.jpeg' }}
                                    style={{ width: IMAGE_SIZE, height: IMAGE_SIZE, borderRadius: 10}}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 20, marginHorizontal: 40, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                <Text style={{flex: 1, fontSize: 26, color: 'white'}}>
                                    Johanna Bloggs {this.state.email}
                                </Text>
                                <Text style={{flex: 0.5, fontSize: 15, color: 'gray', textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 5}}>
                                    0.8 mi
                                </Text>
                                <Text style={{flex: 1, fontSize: 26, color: 'green', textAlign: 'right'}}>
                                    84%
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20, width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 80, marginLeft: 40}}>
                                <Text style={{flex: 1, fontSize: 15, color: 'white'}}>
                                    100% Italian, fun loving, affectionate, young lady who knows what it takes to make a relationship work.
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 30}}>
                                <Text style={{flex: 1, fontSize: 15, color: 'rgba(216, 121, 112, 1)',  marginLeft: 40}}>
                                    INTERESTS
                                </Text>
                                <View style={{flex: 1, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, marginTop: 20}}>
                                    <ScrollView
                                        style={{flex: 1}}
                                        horizontal
                                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                    >
                                        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', height: 170, marginLeft: 40, marginRight: 10}}>
                                            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                                <CustomButton title="Philosophy" selected={true} />
                                                <CustomButton title="Sport" />
                                                <CustomButton title="Swimming" selected={true} />
                                                <CustomButton title="Religion" />
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                                <CustomButton title="Music" />
                                                <CustomButton title="Soccer" selected={true} />
                                                <CustomButton title="Radiohead" selected={true} />
                                                <CustomButton title="Micheal Jackson" />
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                                <CustomButton title="Travelling" selected={true} />
                                                <CustomButton title="Rock'n'Roll" />
                                                <CustomButton title="Dogs" selected={true} />
                                                <CustomButton title="France" selected={true} />
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                    </ScrollView>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 30}}>
                                <Text style={{flex: 1, fontSize: 15, color: 'rgba(216, 121, 112, 1)',  marginLeft: 40}}>
                                    INFO
                                </Text>
                                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 20, marginHorizontal: 30}}>
                                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Age</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Height</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Ethnicity</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Sign</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Religion</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={{flex: 1, marginLeft: 10}}>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>26</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>5'4"</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>White</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>Pisces</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>Catholic</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Body Type</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Diet</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Smoke</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Drink</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoTypeLabel}>Drugs</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={{flex: 1, marginLeft: 10, marginRight: -20}}>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>Fit</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>Vegan</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>No</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>No</Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.infoAnswerLabel}>Never</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>

                        </ScrollView>
                    </View> :
                    <Text>Loading...</Text>
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    statusBar: {
        height: 10,
    },
    navBar: {
        height: 60,
        width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center'
    },
    nameHeader: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 22,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    infoTypeLabel: {
        fontSize: 15,
        textAlign: 'right',
        color: 'rgba(126,123,138,1)',

        paddingBottom: 10,
    },
    infoAnswerLabel: {
        fontSize: 15,
        color: 'white',

        paddingBottom: 10,
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show how you are using `token` in `next screen`?

Comment: @AhsanAli `this.state.token` is undefined in render function in the next screen unfortunately

Comment: `this.state` is relative to the screen where it is defined only unless passed as `props` to another.

Comment: @PritishVaidya I tried to use `this.props.token` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Please add the code for the `two screens`, will take a look into it and also the `navigation mechanism`

Comment: You should not mutate the `state` directly instead use `this.setState({token: responseJson.token});`

Comment: @AhsanAli Ok. I pasted my new code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that fetch is a `async` function and `this` sometimes is not reachable (or at least it what happen to me) so, to fix it I create a variable named `self` before to create the class and I equalize it to `this` like the way Im going to write in the constructor:

```
import{..}...; //your imports

let self;

class YourClass() extends Component{
    constructor(){
        //things you do in your constructor and at the end:
        self = this;
    }
}
```

Then, now you can use state like self.state instead of this.state as `self.state.token = responseJson.token;`.
The problem I see is that if you want to put token in state.token you cant do doing `self.state.token = responseJson.token;`, The way to do it is `self.setState({token:responseJson.token});`
or if you don't need to use the self I told you can do
`this.setState({token:responseJson.token});` and forget all I said before
I hope it works for you.

Comment: I tried it and I still get token undefined in the second screen. I post my code in the original question.

Comment: Seeing your code, where do you connect the state in the first component to the second component named "CustomButton"?

Comment: I mean, the 'state' is a state only to it  own class, the state in the second class have only what state had in it. If you want an state to the whole app (that it seems) you will have to use redux. Here you have a guide . https://medium.com/@jonlebensold/getting-started-with-react-native-redux-2b01408c0053

Comment: Yes, I want something like a "logged in user"

Comment: In the class LoginScreen1 this.state doesn't have token value. You try to access it but it is obviously undefined cause just you doesn't initialize it.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking that the state in LoginScreen1 and LoginScreen2 are the same object??ç

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the scope. Now I'm looking into redux but that seems very complicated.

Comment: It is so hard to understand first but then would become so easy to use it. 
If you don't want redux the only thing comes to my mind is that you pass the state of the first screen to the second screen  by props or by navigation params. :/ Get luck bro!  I hope it would helped

Comment: Now it works if I use AsyncStorage. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ow nice, you could use it too I didn't think about it, the problem is that there you only can store strings and numbers, you cannot store object like JSON unless you convert it into strings

Comment: It is ok for my demo to store only string. I only want basic persistence between screen. if I use the string I can connect to my backend and fetch data from memcached in google appengine. it will work very well.

Comment: Nice, I'm happy to hear it works. I recommend you that if you are going continue programming in React Native, spend a little bit of time to learn about Redux, in big projects , is the base of React. Or at least it use to be. Greetings!